# WiredTiger error (22):'table:sizeStorer' cannot be used until all column groups are created: Invalid argument

Tags: linux, mongodb, arm, ubuntu-16.04, wiredtiger

when i install mognodb on ubuntu 16.04(arm),following error happen
anybody help?

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.20
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2020-12-22T06:46:55.227+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2020-12-22T06:46:55.228+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
+ echo 'waiting for mongodb to start'
+ sleep 1
waiting for mongodb to start
2020-12-22T06:46:55.350+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (22) [1608619615:350786][8:0xffffa3ea2830], WT_SESSION.open_cursor: 'table:sizeStorer' cannot be used until all column groups are created: Invalid argument
2020-12-22T06:46:55.350+0000 I -        [initandlisten] Invariant failure: ret resulted in status BadValue: 22: Invalid argument at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_size_storer.cpp 69
2020-12-22T06:46:55.350+0000 I -        [initandlisten]

***aborting after invariant() failure


2020-12-22T06:46:55.353+0000 F -        [initandlisten] Got signal: 6 (Aborted).

 0xaaaad1f1eff0 0xaaaad1f1e2a0 0xaaaad1f1e778 0xffffa411066c 0xffffa3c51528
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"AAAAD0AE0000","o":"143EFF0","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"AAAAD0AE0000","o":"143E2A0"},{"b":"AAAAD0AE0000","o":"143E778"},{"b":"FFFFA4110000","o":"66C","s":"__kernel_rt_sigreturn"},{"b":"FFFFA3C20000","o":"31528","s":"gsignal"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.4.20", "gitVersion" : "447847d93d6e0a21b018d5df45528e815c7c13d8", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.18.0-147.5.1.el8_1.5es.10.aarch64", "version" : "#1 SMP Wed Nov 18 07:41:30 UTC 2020", "machine" : "aarch64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "AAAAD0AE0000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3982CBDADA6790C3977DDD3D6551B6DF334FAAC7" }, { "b" : "FFFFA4110000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E148215A77BEE73A99AE0E632569A81EC648B267" }, { "b" : "FFFFA4080000", "path" : "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "124D415B526BD3F23D860A22D61E1BB2E78225DB" }, { "b" : "FFFFA3ED0000", "path" : "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "57D86F63CECE2854EEB0BCB2902539F32FF8B74D" }, { "b" : "FFFFA3EB0000", "path" : "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E29A22F305FD4ED854F285075E0FCF108214FB05" }, { "b" : "FFFFA3E80000", "path" : "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "24F2003BAAC8931062D7877508ACF12C16F043BA" }, { "b" : "FFFFA3DD0000", "path" : "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "80D706B4DF38445B5D79F6D178E22119A310BE81" }, { "b" : "FFFFA3DA0000", "path" : "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A05222936FB1A047AC0567B0861730C781C69A23" }, { "b" : "FFFFA3D70000", "path" : "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5B6DA4B4C11C0FD847E788E610B22C253C8BF1EA" }, { "b" : "FFFFA3C20000", "path" : "/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "825D6B66F1FFDA9DF55C4D8EC221D57D8BCC82A4" }, { "b" : "FFFFA4120000", "path" : "/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "18CCB66DA0CF21AB4C1B1FE62B8D01C405A8825A" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x48) [0xaaaad1f1eff0]
 mongod(+0x143E2A0) [0xaaaad1f1e2a0]
 mongod(+0x143E778) [0xaaaad1f1e778]
 (__kernel_rt_sigreturn+0x0) [0xffffa411066c]
 libc.so.6(gsignal+0x38) [0xffffa3c51528]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

when i install mognodb on ubuntu 16.04(arm),following error happen anybody help?
mognodb version 3.4.20,operating system is ubuntu 16.04,running on kubernetes

Comment: Why are you installing an old patch release of an unsupported version?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Most of the time can be successful installation，and this error happens ocasionally. Confusing me is  what do you mean this is an unsupported version? thks

Comment: See https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy. 3.4 reached its end of life in January. At least install the most recent patch release of it.

Comment: And add complete server log to the question.

Comment: my start shell 
```
set -ex

mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf --auth &

t=0
until mongo --eval "db.adminCommand('ping')"; do
  echo "waiting for mongodb to start"
  sleep 1
  t=$(($t+1))
  if [ $t -ge 30 ] ; then
      echo "mongodb did not start, giving up"
      exit 1
  fi
done
```
and the log see answer block
thks

Comment: That is not the server log.